# how to select a div based on the data attribute that matches a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, salesforce

I am trying to use Jquery ui tabs with salesforce communities, if a user is being directed from a different page to the current page, based on the project id of the previous page, the current page needs to highlight the appropriate tab.

> These tabs are generated based on how many project a user
>   has which prevents me from giving them an ID inside the html

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var focusedProject = '{!focusedProjectId}';
    $('.projectTabs').each(function(){
       var id = $(this).data('salesforceprojectid');
       if(focusedProject === id){
         $('*[data-salesforceprojectid="HARD CODED ID"]').addClass('ui-state-active');
       }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Where you see the words **hard coded Id** i want to put the variable `focusedProject` - it doesnt seem this is possible, does anyone know an alternate solution for this?

```
<ul>
  <li class="projectTabs" data-salesforceprojectid="{!projectList.Id}"></li>
  <li class="projectTabs" data-salesforceprojectid="{!projectList.Id}"></li>
  <li class="projectTabs" data-salesforceprojectid="{!projectList.Id}"></li>
  <li class="projectTabs" data-salesforceprojectid="{!projectList.Id}"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible, just stick it in there ?

Comment: why do you even need the `each` loop?

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is more about the templating, and those strings aren't what you've posted, the content inside the curlybraces are replaced by something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't do

```
$('*[data-salesforceprojectid="' + focusedProject  + '"]').addClass('ui-state-active');
```

to make the hard coded part into a variable?

Comment: add the tab class to it and the `each` is not needed as well